Sentry / Nuxt2 integration doesn't work on Azure staging env
I want to integrate Sentry into my Nuxt2/Vue2 project.
My nuxt.config.js looks following:
export default {
  ...
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/sentry'
  ],
  ...
  sentry: {
    dsn: process.env.OPTIMISER_WEB_SENTRY_DSN,
    disabled: process.env.SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT === 'development',
    tracePropagationTargets: [new RegExp(`^${process.env.API_URL}`)],
    tracesSampleRate: 1.0, //  Capture 100% of the transactions
  }
  ...
}

When I'm testing it locally (with commenting the disabled: process.env.SENTRY_ENVIRONMENT === 'development' of course) I'm able to see all the errors in Sentry.
The problem is that when I'm trying to test it on staging (raise the same error there) it doesn't work. I'm hosting my app on Azure, and using bash I've made sure that all the environmental variables are there (I've 'echo-ed' them). Even if I'm deploying configuration without a 'disabled' line to staging, it is still disabled.
I've also integrated 2 of my other apps (Python/FastAPI) and everything works well.
What might be the problem?

Please share the error in text format. I tied with basic Nuxt2 and It worked using staging env
